# How to generate multiple multipart presigned post url to upload a file in boto3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, upload, multipart

I have searched this issue and found multiple solutions but nothing worked yet.

Searched :

*https://sandyghai.github.io/AWS-S3-Multipart-Upload-Using-Presigned-Url/*

*https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2305*

Comment: Please share links which leads to a possible solution

Comment: Show your work please